# PHP garbage collection and functions

Tags: php, memory-leaks, phpquery

I'm using PHPQuery (HTML parser) in a loop, and unsetting the previous document each time by using `phpQuery::unloadDocuments()`. The loop simplifies to:

```
while(...){
  $doc="parsed stuff";
  ...
  unset($doc);
}
```

However, there's memory leak in this because the script runs out of memory after a while. After searching online, someone recommended that to avoid memory leak, I should wrap it in a function, so I changed it to this:

```
function r(){
  $doc="parsed stuff";
  ...
  unset($doc);
}
while(...)
  r();
```

Now, the memory leak stopped. Why is this?

Comment: You mean why there are no memory leak now?

Comment: Any other variables defined in the loop?

Comment: silentboy: Exactly
Koterpillar: There are a ton of variables, upwards of 50, I think.
sectus: 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php, is has good example there.